# Printing specific values from list in Python 3

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a different and shorter way to print specific values in a list without having to repeat print(num[x],num[x],num[x]) many times

```
num=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e"]

print(num[5])
print(num[5], num[12])
```

Comment: `for i in [5,12,16]: print(num[i],end=' ')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just loop like this:

```
for i in [5, 12]:
   print(num[i], end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> num=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> itemgetter(5, 12)(num)
('5', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension:

```
>>> num=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> print( [num[x] for x in (5, 12)] )
['5', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a function.

```
def getVal(List, *index):
    for x in index:
        print(List[x], end=" ")

 num=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e"]
 getVal(num, 1, 5, 3)

 # 1 5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `map()` what you want:

```
>>> num=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> list(map(lambda x: num[x], [5, 12]))
['5', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function :

```
num=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e"]

def index_no(first,second):
    try:
        return (num[first],num[second])
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(index_no(5,12))
```

output:

```
('5', 'c')
```